# How to edit whole post in HTML mode in WordPress gutenberg editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In classic editor, I can write html in the text tab of the editor. But in Gutenberg editor, it seems I can only edit a block in HTML(using the block option "Edit as HTML"). Is there a way to edit the whole post as HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch between the Code editor and Visual editor for the whole post/page via the shortcut: `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + M`. The Code editor enables direct editing of the underlying HTML.

The menu option is also found underneath 'Options' in the top right hand corner of the Edit Post view:
[image: Options]

Be *careful* when editing inner Gutenberg Block HTML code directly as it can potentially introduce validation errors. Use [post revisions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/#displaying-rendered-revisions) to return to the previously valid HTML if you encounter issues and need to go back.